# I need help recreating the flag of Iceland all in HTML or CSS coding

Tags: html, css

I need help recreating the flag of Iceland all in HTML and CSS code, so no `<img>` or whatever. Thank you very much. 
[image]

Comment: http://pattle.github.io/Flags-in-CSS/

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please read the [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask question and describe what you have tried.

Answer (score 3):

Multiple gradient can do this easily:

```css
.flag {
  width:170px;
  height:145px;
  background:
    linear-gradient(blue,blue) 0 0      /50px 50px,
    linear-gradient(blue,blue) 0 100%   /50px 50px,
    linear-gradient(blue,blue) 100% 0   /75px 50px,
    linear-gradient(blue,blue) 100% 100%/75px 50px,
    
    linear-gradient(red,red)   60px 0/ 25px 100%,
    linear-gradient(red,red)   0 60px/ 100% 25px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="flag"></div>
```

Comment: Impressive Especially when compared by the amount of code with another answer

Answer (score 0):

May not be pretty, but here you go.

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="div1"> </div>
  <div class="div2"> </div>
  <div class="div3"> </div>
  <div class="div4"> </div>
  <div class="div5"> </div>
  <div class="div6"> </div>
  <div class="div7"> </div>
  <div class="div8"> </div>
  <div class="div9"> </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 0px;
  grid-row-gap: 0px;
  width: 172px;
  height: 126px;
}

.div1 { 
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2;
  background: blue;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-right: 3px solid white;
  border-bottom: 3px solid white;
}
.div2 { 
  grid-area: 1 / 2 / 2 / 3; 
  background: red;
  width: 20px;
  height: 50px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid red;
}
.div3 { 
  grid-area: 1 / 3 / 2 / 4; 
  background: blue;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  border-left: 3px solid white;
  border-bottom: 3px solid white;
}
.div4 { 
  grid-area: 2 / 1 / 3 / 2; 
  background: red;
  height: 20px;
}
.div5 { 
  grid-area: 2 / 2 / 3 / 3; 
  background: red;
  height: 20px;
}
.div6 { 
  grid-area: 2 / 3 / 3 / 4; 
  background: red;
  height: 20px;
}
.div7 { 
  grid-area: 3 / 1 / 4 / 2; 
  background: blue;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-right: 3px solid white;
  border-top: 3px solid white;
}
.div8 { 
  grid-area: 3 / 2 / 4 / 3; 
  background: red;
  width: 20px;
  height: 50px;
  border-top: 3px solid red;
}
.div9 { 
  grid-area: 3 / 3 / 4 / 4; 
  background: blue;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  border-left: 3px solid white;
  border-top: 3px solid white;
}
```

https://codepen.io/damaho92/pen/QWwWeZO